# Problems setting up a self signed certificate

Tags: swift, https

We have a server that is hosting an HTTPS interface using a self signed certificate (I have been waiting for two weeks to get an approved cert from GoDaddy and I expect I'll get it sooner or later I need to get on with development using the HTTPS interface).

I have a copy of the cert on my local machine as client and have validated that the cert works using curl and by adding the certificate to my Mac so I could run nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://.  The diagnostics worked fine and all tests PASSed.

My iPhone app was using an HTTP interface and I am trying to upgrade it to use HTTPS.  The urlRequest is failing withNSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813).  I have used SecItemAdd to add the certificate (although it is a file converted from .cert to .der types).  I am fairly sure it is working because the next time is do the SecItemAdd I get an errSecDuplicateItem error. While the -9813 would seem to indicate that there is no root certificate.

I have read through many postings one line about -9813 and using a self signed certificate as well as the posting Shipping an App With App Transport Security trying to determine what flags should be set in plist.  Many postings show different ones.  So far I am using:

```
//NSAppTransportSecurity                              <dict>
//    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads                          <Boolean>    Yes
//    NSException Domains                             <dict>
//        <my domain name>                            <dict>
//            NSRequiresCertificateTransparency       <Boolean>    No
//            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads      <Boolean>    No
//            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion            <String>  TLSv1.0
//            NSIncludesSubdomains                    <Boolean>    Yes
//            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy       <Boolean>    Yes
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have read several other posts that say NSAllowArbitraryLoads should be set to No (not Yes).  When I make this change I get: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “35.165.246.8” which could put your confidential information at risk."